# Convert existing dataframe variable to factor in Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know there are many versions to this question, but I am looking for a specific solution. When you have an existing character variable in a **dataframe**, is there an easy method for converting that variable to a factor using the tidyverse format? For example, the 2nd line of code below won't reorder the factor levels, but the last line will. How do I make the 2nd line work? There are situations when this would be useful -- importing and modifying existing datasets. Many Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c('post','pre')) %>%
      as_factor(y, levels = c('pre','post'))

df$y <- factor(df$y, levels = c('pre', 'post'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `fct_relevel` from `forcats`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c('post','pre')) %>% 
       mutate(y = fct_relevel(y, 'pre', 'post'))
```

-output

```
> df1$y
[1] post pre 
Levels: pre post
```

---

Regarding the use of `as_factor`, according to documentation

> Compared to base R, when x is a character, this function creates levels in the order in which they appear, which will be the same on every platform.

i.e. `post`, followed by `pre`

```
> as_factor(c('post','pre'))
[1] post pre 
Levels: post pre
```

whereas the following options will not work as there is no argument named `levels` in `as_factor`

```
> as_factor(c('post','pre'), "pre", "post")
Error: 2 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `..1`
* `..2`

Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> as_factor(c('post','pre'), levels = c("pre", "post"))
Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `levels`

Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Also, in `tidyverse`, we need to extract the column with `pull` or `.$` or else have to modify the column within `mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `relevel`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c('post','pre')) 

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(y = relevel(as.factor(y), 'pre', 'post'))

df$y
levels(df$y)
```

```
  x    y
1 1 post
2 2  pre

> df$y
[1] post pre 
Levels: pre post
> levels(df$y)
[1] "pre"  "post"
```